# BatchScript - catch command result (with whitspace)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to safe the result of a `where` command in a `batch-script`

Without a script (directly in the command prompt), it looks like this:

```
where python
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\short\python.exe
C:\Python\Python36\python.exe
```

but, when catching the result in a script-file:

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%p IN ('where python.exe') DO ECHO %%p
C:\Program
C:\Python\Python36\python.exe
```

the output of the first result ends with the `whitespace`.

Is there a way, to force the command, to assign a fullstring to the var, without any external tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%p ....
```

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation.